# задача на матрицы

Tags: python

Задача:
На вход программе подаются два натуральных числа nn и mm, каждое на отдельной строке — количество строк и столбцов в матрице. Далее вводятся сами элементы матрицы — слова, каждое на отдельной строке; подряд идут элементы сначала первой строки, затем второй, и т.д.

Напишите программу, которая сначала считывает элементы матрицы один за другим, затем выводит их в виде матрицы.

Вводные данные:

```
4
2
и
швец
и
жнец
и
на
дуде
игрец
```

Должен вывести:

```
и швец
и жнец
и на
дуде игрец
```

код:

```
rows, cols = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = []
temp = []
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        temp.append(input())
    matrix.append(temp)
    temp.clear()
for i in matrix:
    print(*i)
```

И так вопрос, почему после очистки temp у меня очищяется matrix?

Comment: `matrix.append(temp)` -> `matrix.append(temp[:])`.

Answer (score 1):

[Ссылка на такую же проблему с решением](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606601/python-append-a-list-to-another-list-and-clear-the-first-list)

Если в кратце, то метод append не просто добавляет элемент в конец списка, а создает ссылку на нее. Вы методом clear удаляете то, на что ссылается ваша matrix. Ваш код будет работать, если изменить на это:

```
rows, cols = int(input("vvedite1")), int(input("vvedite2"))
matrix = []
temp = []
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        temp.append(input('vvedite'))
    matrix.append(temp[:]) // изменения здесь
    temp.clear()
for i in matrix:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как и сказал [@Сергей Махнёв](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/460895/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%B2), все дело в том, что в `matrix` добавляется ссылка на массив `temp`. Хочу лишь предложить несколько "сокращений" решения.

```
rows, cols = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(rows):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(cols):
        matrix[i].append(input())        
for i in matrix:
    print(*i)
```

---

```
rows, cols = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(rows):
    matrix.append([input() for j in range(cols)])
for i in matrix:
    print(*i)
```

---

```
rows, cols = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = [[input() for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
for i in matrix:
    print(*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Да я понимаю, что методом append добавляются ссылки на элементы а потом они удаляются но я категорически не понимаю почему тогда этот код работает правильно

```
rows, cols = int(input()), int(input())
matrix = []
for i in range(rows):
    temp = []
    for j in range(cols):
        temp.append(input())
    matrix.append(temp)
for i in matrix:
    print(*i)
```

Comment: Не оформляйте новые вопросы в виде ответов. Здесь у вас с помощью `temp = []` каждый раз создаётся **новый список**. Который не имеет никакой связи с предыдущими списками.